# Smallest sum of subarray with sum greater than a given value

Tags: arrays, algorithm, performance, numbers

**Input**: Array of **N** positive numbers and a value **X** such that **N** is small compared to **X**
**Output**: Subarray with sum of all its numbers equal to **Y > X**, such that there is no other subarray with sum of its numbers bigger than **X** but smaller than **Y**.

Is there a polynomial solution to this question? If so, can you present it?

Comment: do you have a restriction on the elements in the array?

Comment: Do the sub array values have to be adjacent within the larger array?  Does it matter if the solution is not unique?

Comment: @svs Generally **No**. But if it helps you can restrict them to no duplicates, positive values, smaller than 10^10

Comment: Is `O(X*Y)` acceptable?

Comment: @JeffIrwin There could be multiple solutions equal to **Y**, I will be satisfied with finding just one of them. And there is no restriction of the result sub array.

Comment: @svs it could be a good start.

Comment: With nonnegative array elements, you have a linear (in the size of the array) algorithm (assuming all arithmetic operations are O(1)) if a "subarray" must be contiguous. If a subarray need not be contiguous, I'm not sure what complexity you can reach.

Comment: @DanielFischer Yeah then it would be trivial, but the sub array doesn't have to be contiguous.

Comment: Expected that, would have been too good to be true.

Comment: @DanielFischer I found a lower bounds by sorting the array and summing the values starting from higher first until it's bigger than **Y**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the other answers indicate this is a NP-Complete problem which is called the "[Knapsack Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem)". So there is no polynomial solution. But it has a pseudo polynomial time algorithm. [This explains what pseudo polynomial is](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-meaning-of-pseudo-polynomial-time-complexity-I-saw-that-Knapsack-runs-in-pseudo-polynomial-time-I-read-about-this-here-Pseudo-polynomial-time-but-I-am-not-able-to-follow-I-want-to-understand-the-concept-of-pseudo-polynomial-running-time-and-how-knapsack-runs-in-pseudo-polynomial-time).

[A visual explanation of the algorithm](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8LusJS5-AGo).

[And some code](http://www.programminglogic.com/knapsack-problem-dynamic-programming-algorithm/).

If this is work related (I met this problem a few times already, in various disguises) I suggest introducing additional restrictions to simplify it. If it was a general question you may want to check other NP-Complete problems as well. [One such list.](http://www.users.csbsju.edu/~lziegler/CS338/NP-Complete%20Problems.html)

**Edit 1:**

AliVar made a good point. The given problem searches for Y > X and the knapsack problem searches for Y < X. So the answer for this problem needs a few more steps. When we are trying to find the minimum sum where Y > X we are also looking for the maximum sum where S < (Total - X). The second part is the original knapsack problem. So;

1. Find the total
2. Solve knapsack for S < (Total - X)
3. Subtrack the list of items in knapsack solution from the original input.
4. This should give you the minimum Y > X

Comment: In the original Knapsack problem we have Y<X. Thus I think this problem needs a minor modification to be considered a Knapsack problem. Right?

Comment: My interpretation is in both cases the balance point is Y=X and we are trying to find the best approximation. I don’t think approaching it from the left or right changes the nature of the problem. But you are right my answer needs clarification. Please see Edit 1. Thanks for the input :)

Comment: This will not work for 3,1,9,10,7; x = 12. Total is 30. knapsack solution for Total - X = 11 > [10] . The subtraction from original input gives: [3,1,9,7] = 19. While the solution to the problem is [10, 3] =13.

Comment: I meant this: Total - X = 30 - 12 = 18; maxSum for Y < 18 = (7 + 10) = 17; MinSum for Y > 12  is there for =>  (3,1,9) = 13;

Answer (score 2):

Let `A` be our array. Here is a `O(X*N)` algorithm:

```
initialize set S = {0}
initialize map<int, int> parent
best_sum = inf
best_parent = -1
for a in A
     Sn = {}
     for s in S
         t = s + a
         if t > X and t < best_sum
             best_sum = t
             best_parent = s
         end if
         if t <= X
             Sn.add(t)
             parent[t] = s
         end if
     end for
     S = S unite with Sn
end for
```

To print the elements in the best sum print the numbers:

```
Subarray = {best_sum - best_parent}
t = best_parent
while t in parent.keys()
    Subarray.add(t-parent[t])
    t = parent[t]
end while
print Subarray
```

The idea is similar to the idea of dynamic programming. We just calculate all reachable (those that could be obtained as a subarray sum) sums that are less than `X`. For each element `a` in the array `A` you could either choose to participate in the sum or not. At the update step `S = S unite with Sn` `S` represent all sums in which `a` does not participate while `Sn` all sum in which `a` do participate.

You could represent `S` as a boolean array setting a item true if this item is in the set. Note that the length of this boolean array would be at most `X`.

Overall, the algorithm is `O(X*N)` with memory usage `O(X)`.

Comment: How do you choose the value **Y**? Also can you give a brief words explanation to what you are doing here. Btw I didn't saw that you used **X**.

Comment: What is `p`?  I assumed it is the same as `parent`, but when I try to print the elements, it does not work.  However, your algorithm does give the correct `best_sum` (verified by brute-force).

Comment: @JeffIrwin yea, `p` should be `parent`. It should be fine. I will try to test it.

Comment: @svs  I think my original implementation was wrong, but your edit cleared things up.  I was getting the correct sum with an off-by-one error in `parent`, now it all works.

Answer (score 1):

I think this problem is NP-hard and the subset sum can be reduced to it. Here is my reduction:
For an instance of the subset sum with set S={x1,...,xn} it is desired to find a subset with sum t. Suppose d is the minimum distance between two non-equal xi and xj. Build S'={x1+d/n,...,xn+d/n} and feed it to your problem. Suppose that your problem found an answer; i.e. a subset D' of S' with sum Y>t which is the smallest sum with this property. Name the set of original members of D' as D. Three cases may happen:
1) Y = t + |D|*d/n which means D is the solution to the original subset sum problem.
2) Y > t + |D|*d/n which means no answer set can be found for the original problem.
3) Y < t + |D|*d/n. In this case assign t=Y and repeat the problem. Since the value for the new t is increased, this case will not repeat exponentially. Therefore, the procedure terminates in polynomial time.

Comment: Looks interesting! I edited the question based on your answer to be more specific in what am I looking for. Please tell me if this change your result.

Comment: You have the right idea, but case 3 is a problem -- it's not clear that t will increase fast enough.  The problem occurs because you aren't choosing d quite right...  Even if the smallest difference of any non-equal xi and xj is d, the smallest nonzero difference between the sums of any two *disjoint sets of* numbers in S could be arbitrarily smaller -- e.g. S={1, 3, 4, 5, 6.001, 7.001} has d=1 and thus d/n=1/6, but can produce a difference of (6.001+7.001)-(1+3+4+5) = 0.002.  Instead, pick d to be the **largest common divisor** of all numbers in S ...

Comment: ... Now the difference between any two disjoint sets of numbers in S must be an integer multiple of d, which means that case 3 can't happen -- no other subset E of S can map to an E' of S' that "sneaks in front of" the "right" D' (i.e. the one that maps back to D as per case 2).  (Note: taking LCDs implies that the algorithm will only work for rational numbers, which is only a restriction in theory, since in practice irrational numbers can't be represented on computers anyway...)